# how to available plug-in for <object> tag?

Tags: google-chrome, object-tag

How do I available plug-in for this < object > tag?

```
  function load_about(){    
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="about.html" > </object>';
  }
```

when I call the function using the browser google chrome this shows.
[image: No plugin available]

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Missing type="text/html" or a typo as in the question's code example (?) results in error message in chrome (but not in firefox).